# だけでなく and にとどまらず

Tags: grammar, words, meaning, usage, word-usage

I know that there are a lot of expressions that have similar meaning in Japanese. In JLPT N3 grammar, there's だけでなく that means 'not only...but also...'. And lately, I found the expression にとどまらず in JLPT N1 grammar list that has the exact meaning as だけでなく. The only difference that I know is that だけでなく can be attached to Noun, Verb, and Adjective. Meanwhile にとどまらず can only be attached to Noun and Verb. But, I want to know if there are other differences regarding their meaning and usage. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They have different meanings. Because they mean different things, you can't freely replace one by the other.

1. 「とどまらず」is a negation of 「とどまる」, and 「のみならず」 is a negation of 「のみなり」. Here, the 「とどまる」 is a verb, the　「のみ」　is an adverbial particle, and the 「なり」 is an auxiliary verb of determination.

Having said that, the meanings the two words have are:

> (1) 「とどまらない」＝"it does not end there"

Meaning that there is a suggestion of on-going continuousness.

> (2) 「のみならず」＝"not limited to"

Meaning something is not limited to something, suggesting the infinite possibility.

Because the two are common in terms of not having temporal discontinuation in "continuousness" and "infinite possibility", they tend to be similar.
However, the difference between the two is that while the word 「とどまらない」 suggests "ongoing", the word 「のみならず」 suggests a state. The former is used in dynamic situations, and the latter is used in undynamic situations.

2. Replacement

> (1)  「彼は学問にとどまらず、芸術の才能がある。」（Ｘ）
>   　　「彼は学問**のみならず**、芸術の才能がある。」（✓）

Since 「才能がある("having a talent") indicates a state, 「とどまらず」 which expresses "ongoing-ness" is unsuitable.

> (2) 「彼の活動範囲はAにとどまらず、Bにまで及ぶ」（✓）
>   　　「彼の活動範囲はAのみならず、Bにまで及ぶ」（✓）

If you interpret this as something "dynamic" as is "the scope of action is expanded to ...", you can use the word 「とどまらず」, and if you interpret this as a "state" as in "the scope of action throughout ...", you can also use the word 「のみならず」.

> (3) 「彼は成功にとどまらず、社会貢献に尽力した」（✓）
>   　　「彼は成功のみならず、社会貢献に尽力した」（✓）

The first one has two verbs 「（成功に）とどまらず」 and 「（社会貢献に）尽力した」, but the second one has only one verb 「（社会貢献に）尽力した」, so the word 「成功」 has no choice but to also depend on the verb 「尽力した」.
The sentence ends up meaning "became committed to both success and social contribution," and it does not render the nuance of "couldn't be content with the success and made a contribution to the society." This is because of the 「のみ」 being an adverbial particle on which a noun depends.

Comment: 「〇」と「✓」は、それぞれどういう意味ですか。

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, だけでなく also suggests "a state" right? But I want to ask something else. Does it have to be in formal situation for me to use にとどまらず?

Comment: @miki This is a detailed answer, but the original question actually asks about だけでなく rather than のみならず.  Do you think you could add a little bit to explain how the answer applies to だけでなく as well?

Comment: @chocolate 「〇」は「✓」の間違いです。すみません。

Comment: @snailboat  I had to actually go look it up on the internet... Sorry... だけでなく is the colloquial version of のみならず。They both mean the same. のみならず is the old version of だけでなく。Having said that, my initial answer regarding のみならずdirectly applies to だけでなく. I apologize for my carelessness.

Comment: ＠Raka This is not my field of expertise, so I don't know if I can give you the correct answer, but I don't think I've ever heard a person say 「とどまらず」 in a casual conversation. To me, it's something found in newspaper so yea, like you said, it must be used in formal situations. Sorry for being ambiguous...

Comment: Gosh... me and the carelessness... I'm so sorry guys...

Comment: @user170461 thank you, but I have one more question. We can say something like 「私だけでなく私の妻も…」 but,can we use にとどまらず instead? I tried to look for sentences with だけでなく and にとどもらず. There a lot of sentences that use だけでなく to add another subject, but I got no sentence with にとどまらず that use it to add subject. Thank you

Comment: @Raka Yes, it sounds very formal, but you can use にとどまらず to add another subject. BUT!  「のみ」or 「だけ」(both meaning "only or not just") must come before 「にとどまらず」。So the sentence  would be like this: 「私だけ（orのみ）にとどまらず私の妻も・・・。」 I googled the phrases and 「私だけにとどまらず」 gave me 27,500 results while 「私のみにとどまらず」only gave me 9 results. In my opinion, they're both formal, but だけis a bit more casual than のみ。Hope it makes sense to you.

Comment: @user170461 And is it true, what I said earlier about にとどまらず can't be attached to adjective? You said that にとどまらず suggests a dynamic situation, so I assume that sentence with adjective as it's predicate like 「その鞄は大きいだけでなく軽い。」only suggests a state, so it can't use にとどまらず. Thanks for all of your answers

Comment: @Raka You got it right! Your example sentence and the explanation after that are perfect.

Comment: @user170461 I found a sentence, 彼は哲学にとどまらず科学に興味を持っていた。 興味を持っていた means 'having an interest', so it indicates a state, right? So why does it use にとどまらず?

Comment: @Raka If you go back to the 2. of Replacement that I wrote in the answer, having an interest should could be perceived as a state or dynamic since it can also be interpreted as "the scope of his interest has expanded to...".

Comment: But in the case of "having a talent", I personally think it would be a bit strange if it became interpreted as "the scope of his talent has been expanded to ..." because talent is something you just _naturally have_ whereas interest is something that you can selectively _choose to have_ maybe today, tomorrow ... You know? Where did you find that sentence?